# Port a domain address to a LAN address

Tags: networking

In an Android device, is it possible to port a URL such as `www.example.com` to a local network address such as `192.168.0.2:8081`?

Do I need to install an application on that device?

Comment: Please read the android tag. You are asking an off-topic question.  See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a app, but root access, it can be done editing the hosts file in android /system/etc/hosts, although you likely need a computer with adb and some routing skills. Perhaps a honeypot would get the job done with less hassle.

Comment: Glad to help, things should be easier to move on from there.  Good luck, and thanks for the votes. :)